# Using KDE in Qt Creator on Windows

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5, kde-plasma

I am new to Qt Creator and would like to ask about the configuration of KDE libraries in Qt Creator. I had downloaded Qt 5.2 and would like to use the KDE libraries for some GUI development. In addition,I am currently using Windows 7 OS for my development. I had done a bit of research but I can't really find the KDE libraries for windows. As for configuration method, it is just directing the libraries to the project directory and including commands like this:

```
 LIBS += -lkdeui
```

in the .pro file?

Thank you everyone for helping.

Answer (score 1):

KDE has a project to port KDE apps in windows. you can find it here h[ttp://windows.kde.org/](http://windows.kde.org/) . You can change your windows appearance to KDE look which is called OXYGEN. if you want to change the look of your application or you want to use other KDE libraries download it and link your application against it. be sure to use the binary that is compiled against your version of Qt.